# Control the Mouse and Keyboard from .Net (like java.awt.Robot)

Tags: java, c#, .net, awtrobot

I have a Java app that uses [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to control the mouse and keyboard. I would like to translate this to C#, but I can't seem to find a decent substitute with my limited knowledge of the .Net framework. I have found [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), but that seems to require using their scripting language. I have also seen `PostMessage` mentioned, but I can't find that on MSDN. Does anyone have ideas/suggestions on what to use?

Comment: You may want ti investigate Coded UI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Comment: I would, but that seems to require VS pro, while I only have the community edition

Comment: What about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't work either. I should have specified that this needs to work globally on the whole system, not just the app itself.